# Internal url rewriting with Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What I'm trying to do is redirecting requests on http://example.com/tel.php to http://example.com/default/index/tel without showing any redirection to the user. I'm doing this in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^tel\.php$ /default/index/tel [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

however the redirection shows to the user (HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently) which I'm trying to avoid.

How to solve this ?

Comment: [look this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042234/301-redirect-with-custom-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your rules and optionally add a trailing slash if

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^tel\.php$ /default/index/tel [NC,L]
# make it as this if /default/index/tel/ is a real directory
# RewriteRule ^tel\.php$ /default/index/tel/ [NC,L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.